# 3D equivalent to ArcGIS API?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online, 3d, google-earth

I am currently working on a 3D mapping project. And I have created some KML files from ArcGIS Online, and I have edited them in Google Earth to adjust the 3D attributes. I am also designing a webpage with JavaScript, CSS, and HTML to display the results with 3D features. I have brought in the Google Earth API, and it properly displays what I want it to, but it is also very tricky to get anything to work in terms of creating functions to interact with those layers, rather I am just left to embedding them in the API. I know that this type of stuff is doable with ArcGIS Online and the scenes provided there, but I am also running into a lot of difficulty with uploading the layers/scenes from ArcGIS Pro to ArcGIS Online, and I would like to be able to have mroe control over what capabilities I am putting in there (which using JS API helps me to accomplish).

I really would like to stick to ArcGIS rather than Google, as I have more experience with using the ArcGIS JS API, and I was wondering if there is a 3D equivalent to ArcGIS JS API currently available, I have not been able to find anything yet, but I may be overlooking something out there, or searching for the wrong things.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're in luck.  the beta version of the 4.0 ArcGIS API for JavaScript includes 3D support and was released on July 16th.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/beta/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking into Cesium: http://cesiumjs.org/

I have been using it for quite a while and found it to be a great 3D solution. It is open source and provides for additional things like 3D terrain, vector graphics, billboards and 3D models.

Comment: Does Cesium support KMLs?

Comment: Yes it does. Here is an example: http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=KML.html&label=All

Comment: Thank you! This looks very interactive and easy to manipulate, I will try this out.